# Ask about scroll implementation of a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can they implement the scrolling function on [this site](http://megastar.vn/mema)? I tried to read the source of the file, but honestly it is too much for me to grab at a time. Could you please break it down for me or propose another site with the same functionality but is easier to understand?

Thank you and best regards,

Comment: so what you actually want ? do something for you?

Comment: Well it is not working for me, I get  DOM Exceptions. Can't even use the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **jQuery Scroll Path** it will do effects like this by defining a custom path that the browser follows when scrolling.

You can find more information about it [here](https://github.com/JoelBesada/scrollpath).

Watch the demo [here](http://joelb.me/scrollpath/).

Comment: Great help indeed, thank you